# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException not able to fetch input integers from console

Tags: java

I am trying to fetch input from console but don't know why it is showing error.

I am trying to print sum of prime numbers between two numbers.

i am trying this on online learning platform of ManipalProlearn.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfPrimeNumbers {
    /**
    * Main method
    * @param args 
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1=scan.nextInt();
        int n2=scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        if((n1<3 || n1>1000)&&(n1>n2))
        {
            System.out.print("INVALID_INPUT");
        }
        else{
            int sum=0;
            for(int i=n1;i<=n2;i++)
            {
                isprime(i);
                sum+=i;
            }
            System.out.print(sum);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isprime(int i){
        int j;
        for(j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)  return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at SumOfPrimeNumbers.main(SumOfPrimeNumbers.java:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the scanner, like in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-nextint-method-in-java-with-examples/

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s); 

    while (scanner.hasNext()) { 

        // if the next is a Int, 
        // print found and the Int 
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) { 
            System.out.println("Found Int value :"
                               + scanner.nextInt()); 
        } 

        // if no Int is found, 
        // print "Not Found:" and the token 
        else { 
            System.out.println("Not found Int value :"
                               + scanner.next()); 
        } 
    }
```

so in your case, use a list where you store those numbers and the while condition will be `(list.size() < 2 && scanner.hasNext())`